# Determine if users can RDP after Windows Update

Tags: windows-server-2016, rdp

I'm automating windows updates for a set of SQL servers, mostly running on Windows Server 2016. Typically after you install updates you have to reboot, and there is a period of time after rebooting where the server is applying updates and users can't remote into the server (but the server is up and services like SQL still run). In my automation, I would like to wait until that period of time is over before reporting a successful update. Is there an indicator that I can check remotely that will determine whether a user can remote in?

I've checked the main RDP services (termservice, SessionEnv and UmRdpService) during this period and they are all running, and I've tested connections to port 3389, so if there's some sort of indicator, it is likely not them. Maybe there is a field somewhere that states that windows is applying updates? All of the servers are virtualized through VMWare if it matters.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: I am about to reboot one of my Server 2016 machines, and will see if there is any event in the Event Log that is easy to point to for this.